# Service Reference for android?

Tags: java, android, vb.net, service-reference

I have a service which I need to access from an android app. The goal is simply to send a number value from a textbox and get a result string back.

I know it is possible to do so in VB using a Service Reference, which I have done. Here is the sample code :

```
    Private Async Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim service As New   ServiceReference2.Service1Client(ServiceReference2.Service1Client.EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IService1)
    Try
        lblReturn.Text = Await service.GetDataAsync(CInt(txtValueSent.Text))
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblReturn.Text = ex.Message
        If Not ex.InnerException.Message Is Nothing Then
            lblReturn.Text = lblReturn.Text + ex.InnerException.Message
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

After research I can't seem to find any way to have a quick and simple result like it is possible to with Visual Studio using Android Studio

Are there any tools available which work in a similar way ?
If not which process would be recommanded to achieve the same result ?
Are there any usefull links which could help enlighten me?

Comment: [Sure](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).

Comment: Do you have any useful links which could help me in my search ?

Comment: My bad didn't notice the link. Thanks